# IE makes CrossDomain requests on the same domain

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I have a problem: on the one domain - IE makes crossdomain requests instead of normal requests. 
Request is very simple: using **jQuery -> $.load()** function.
FireFox does such request:

> GET http://my.domain/ru/realty/edit HTTP/1.1 Host: my.domain
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Referer:
>   http://my.domain/ Cookie:
>   __utma=87823819.1160716052.1363709577.1367502014.1367509134.33; __utma=30543128.779215939.1367937097.1367937097.1367998627.2; __utmz=70583128.1367937097.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); JSESSIONID=9E43A28EBC2A1C1AE17CCCEDD6123222;
>   __utmb=90563128.4.8.1367598328775; __utmc=90583128 Connection: keep-alive

But IE does such request:

> GET http://my.domain/ru/realty/edit HTTP/1.1 Accept: */*
>   Origin: http://my.domain Accept-Language: ru-RU Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0) Host: my.domain DNT: 1 Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache

Why IE make cross-domain request?

Comment: How is IE making a cross domain request?

Comment: I don't know how. But it makes it. But I don't want it :) I want IE makes normal requests instead of crossDomain because it all happens on one domain.